# Delegate seems to not be working, according to the console

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uipageviewcontroller

Here i have two classes. How do I make `JournalPage` call `JournalEntryController` `didSubmit` method.

```
protocol JournalPageDelegate {
     func didSubmit(for commentText: String)
}

class JournalPage: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    var delegate: JournalPageDelegate?

    fileprivate let textView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()

        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Enter Text Here.", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)])

        textView.textColor = UIColor.black
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        textView.becomeFirstResponder()
        textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRange(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: textView.beginningOfDocument)
        textView.attributedText = attributedText
        return textView
}()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =  UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(save))
    }

    @objc func save() {
        print("saving")
        guard let commentText = textView.text else { return }

        delegate?.didSubmit(for: commentText)
    }
```

And here is the class where I want to call the method.

```
class JournalEntryController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, JournalPageDelegate  {

    func didSubmit(for commentText: String) {
        print("Testing for text")
    }
}
```

And for some reason, I don't see "Testing" on the console when I tap save on `JournalPage` class. How do I make `JournalPage` call `JournalEntryController` `didSubmit` method?

Comment: How does your `JournalEntryController` set itself as the delegate?

Comment: Set the delegate to self in JournalEntryController.

Comment: I think, you need to add delegate  from your class where you want call

Comment: You also need to make the delegate weak and have the protocol be a class protocol. Otherwise you will have memory leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you used delegates you need to pass that delegate from one view controller to another view controller. 
According to Apple definition:

**Delegation is a simple and powerful pattern in which one object in a program acts on behalf of, or in coordination with, another object. The delegating object keeps a reference to the other object–the delegate–and at the appropriate time sends a message to it. The message informs the delegate of an event that the delegating object is about to handle or has just handled. The delegate may respond to the message by updating the appearance or state of itself or other objects in the application, and in some cases it can return a value that affects how an impending event is handled. The main value of delegation is that it allows you to easily customize the behavior of several objects in one central object.**

The missing part you are doing is that you are not calling the delegate for expample you called `JournalTextDelegate` in your class  `JournalEntryController` so you need to call this `JournalTextDelegate` to your `JournalPage`.

for example: Suppose your going to another view controller through push method

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “identifierier”) as! JournalPage
 vc.delegate = self // you need to call this delegate
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(notifDetailVCObj, animated: true)
```

And it will work fine. For reference see documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html

Comment: Thanks for answer and link. I restarted my page and made a new one based on your answers and documentation. I now used ".pushViewController" method(I think I had .present previously)  and the "save" button worked on that view controller being pushed.

However, I didn't use navigation bar's right item this time. I've decided to remove the navigation bar, and manually added a button. The delegation technique worked.

Thank you for the answers! I understood view hierarchies and navigation more.

Answer (score 0):

You delegate from pageview controller:

```
{your JournalPage controller object}.delegate = self
```