# swift change theme using delegate and protocol on many view controller

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I'm trying to use delegate and protocol first time.

I want to change the theme across many view controller.

Then on any controller which has protocol to change theme

When I go to this controller now I expect theme to be new but is old.

**I do not go from theme controller to where them has changed**

---

**My code**

```
protocol ThemeDelegate: class {
    func changeTheme(theme: UIColor)
}


class FirstController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, ThemeDelegate {

    var newTheme: UIColor  = .red

    func changeTheme(theme: UIColor) {
        newTheme = theme
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = newTheme
    }
}

ThemeController {

    weak var themeDelegate: ThemeDelegate?

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {        
        let theme = .blue        
        themeDelegate?.changeTheme(theme: theme)        
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: themeCellId, for: indexPath) as! ThemeCell
        cell.themeImageView.image = UIImage(named: "theme cell image")
        return cell
    }
}
```

[this is order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZlFj.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8TQN.jpg)

Comment: you missed to call delegate

Comment: thank you. can you say where?

Comment: Did you created this protocol in your CollectionViewCell class?

Comment: protocol is in a file called protocol.swift alone

Comment: And where you created this `weak var themeDelegate: ThemeDelegate?`. ??

Comment: yes in theme controller a collection view

Comment: The in `cellForItem` method call `cell.themeDelegate = self`

Comment: Value of type 'ThemeCell' has no member 'themeDelegate'

Comment: Its because you didn't called themeDelegate where you calling this delegate function just call delegate. check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52327377/delegate-seems-to-not-be-working-according-to-the-console/52327562#52327562

Comment: sorry. i do not understand

Comment: "you need to pass that delegate from one view controller to another view controller" i am not using storyboard.

Comment: Can you show your whole code

Comment: Just to answer your question, and why it doesn't work, I've posted an answer. 
But, all of these seem like bits and pieces since you have not made your objective clear. 
Please post more about the two controllers, how you handle their instances and such so that we can probably be of more help

Comment: thank you for the answer. i understand some more. i will work now to add more information to the question. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to make it simple:-

1) First, declare a protocol:-

```
protocol ThemeDelegate{
    func changeTheme(theme: String, fontColor: UIColor, alpha: CGFloat)
}
```

2) Have a variable of that protocol in your ThemeController:

```
open var themeDelegate: ThemeDelegate? = nil
```

3) Call the delegate functions through `themeDelegate`:- (you've done this right till this step)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    themeDelegate?.changeTheme(theme: theme, fontColor: fontColor, alpha: alpha)
}
```

4) You need to conform your `AnyController` as the delegate, like `yourThemeControllerInstance.delegate = self` and you've done that as well.

**It doesn't work because you've declared a new instance of `ThemeController` and have conformed `AnyController` to be the delegate of that new instance which supposedly has the same old theme:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let themeController = ThemeController() // This is a new instance which you have created, so gets initialised with old theme. You have made your class to be the delegate of this instance
    themeController.themeDelegate = self
}
```

In order for your delegate to work as expected, **you need the same instance of `ThemeController`** where you change your theme

Answer (score 0):

You can set delegate but careful view needs a be load.

You do this also with **notifications** and send all viewControllers with conforms Theme

**1 - Your Step**

```
import UIKit

protocol ThemeDelegate: class {
    func changeTheme(theme: String, fontColor: UIColor, alpha: CGFloat)
}

class ThemeController: UIViewController {

    weak var themeDelegate: ThemeDelegate?

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        themeDelegate?.changeTheme(theme: theme, fontColor: fontColor, alpha: alpha)
    }

}

class XViewController: UIViewController {


    // Create an instance
    lazy var themeController = ThemeController()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // We need call loadView becase collectionView needs to be show
        themeController.loadView()
        themeController.themeDelegate = self

    }

}
extension XViewController: ThemeDelegate {
    // And we conform ThemeDelegate
    func changeTheme(theme: String, fontColor: UIColor, alpha: CGFloat) {
        // TODO UI
    }
}
```

**2 - Observer Step**

```
// Sometimes we need update multiple viewControllers and we should use notification and observers


// We create a model
struct Theme {
    let theme: String
    let fontColor: UIColor
    let alpha: CGFloat
}

// We need a protocol for we don't want all view controller listen theme
protocol Themeable: class {
    func listenTheme()
    func didThemeChange(theme: Theme)
}


// Global notification name
let themeableNotificationName = Notification.Name(rawValue: "ThemeableNotification")

// Our protocol extension and observer notification
extension Themeable where Self: UIViewController {
    func listenTheme() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: themeableNotificationName, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
            guard let theme = notification.object as? Theme else { return }
            self?.didThemeChange(theme: theme)
        }
    }

}


// Notification sender themeController
class NotifyThemeController: UIViewController {


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Create a model and post
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: themeableNotificationName, object: Theme(theme: "Lorem", fontColor: .red, alpha: 1.0), userInfo: nil)
    }

}

// YViewController
class YViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // We need call this method for observer
        listenTheme()
    }


}
// YViewController conforms Themeable
extension YViewController: Themeable {
    func didThemeChange(theme: Theme) {
        // TODO UI
    }

}
// ZViewController
class ZViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // We need call this method for observer
        listenTheme()
    }


}
// ZViewController conforms Themeable
extension ZViewController: Themeable {
    func didThemeChange(theme: Theme) {
        // TODO UI
    }

}
```

Have Fun!

Comment: really thank you for this answer. i am understanding a lot more. very helpful to know 2 ways.