# How to dynamically switch UI theme based on different user types in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, swift4.2, xcode10.1

In my app, I've got a scenario where I need to switch the UI theme design based on user type. For eg: In my Type1 user flow it goes like `Registration Screen -> HomePage Screen` and in my Type 2 user it should go like `Registration Screen-> Contact Screen -> Home Page Screen`. And the UI design and themes are different in the case of Type 2 user. For achieve this, below is my sample code flow which is implemented currently.

**RegistrationViewController**

(This view is available for both users but UI theme is different, like navigation bar color, bg color, button color, fonts, images etc)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViews()
    }


private func setupViews(){

        if Utilities.isUserType1{
            setupViewsForType1User() //Adds themes for type 1 user
        } else {
            setupViewsForType2User() //Adds themes for type 2 user
    }

}

 @IBAction func continueAction(_ sender: Any) {

    if Utilities.isUserType1{
            goToContactView() //Goes to ContactViewController
        } else {
            gotToHomeView() //Goes to HomeViewController
    }

}
```

**ContactViewController** 
(This view is only available for type1 user)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViews()
    }


private func setupViews(){

        //Setupviews 

}

 @IBAction func continueAction(_ sender: Any) {

            gotToHomeView()

}
```

**HomeViewController** 
(This view is available for both users but UI theme is different as mentioned in Registration)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViews()
    }



private func setupViews(){

        if Utilities.isUserType1{
            setupViewsForType1User()
        } else {
            setupViewsForType2User()
    }

}
```

This works fine, but the problem here is now I've defined an `isUserType` in Utilities and its not perfectly scalable. For each flow and UI change, I need to put an if-else condition based on this parameter. So, now if I have another user type that needs to be added in the future I would again need another if-else statement and switch UI and flow based on that.

Is there any better approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Your theme definition should be based on userType/category

Answer (score 1):

You can check for change **Theme** [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57069036/swift-change-theme-using-delegate-and-protocol-on-many-view-controller/57069984#57069984)

You need change dynamic theme based on different user so post notification and apply theme what you need

```
// We create a model
struct Theme {
    let theme: String
    let fontColor: UIColor
    let alpha: CGFloat
}

// We need a protocol for we don't want all view controller listen theme
protocol Themeable: class {
    func listenTheme()
    func didThemeChange(theme: Theme)
}


// Global notification name
let themeableNotificationName = Notification.Name(rawValue: "ThemeableNotification")

// Our protocol extension and observer notification
extension Themeable where Self: UIViewController {
    func listenTheme() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: themeableNotificationName, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
            guard let theme = notification.object as? Theme else { return }
            self?.didThemeChange(theme: theme)
        }
    }

}


// Notification sender themeController
class NotifyThemeController: UIViewController {


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Create a model and post
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: themeableNotificationName, object: Theme(theme: "Lorem", fontColor: .red, alpha: 1.0), userInfo: nil)
    }

}

// YViewController
class YViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // We need call this method for observer
        listenTheme()
    }


}
// YViewController conforms Themeable
extension YViewController: Themeable {
    func didThemeChange(theme: Theme) {
        // TODO UI
    }

}
// ZViewController
class ZViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // We need call this method for observer
        listenTheme()
    }


}
// ZViewController conforms Themeable
extension ZViewController: Themeable {
    func didThemeChange(theme: Theme) {
        // TODO UI
    }

}
```

Have Fun!